# Content not printed when building HTML table with JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I don't get any error in Netbeans, but it doesn't execute nothing except the "Hola?" that i put for test,
I think the main error is in the Printwriter command, it doesn't generate anything in my display,

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Página Nacho</title>
</head>
  <%@page import="ejemplo.BaseDatos" %>
  <%  out.println("Hola?");
    out.println("<body>");
      BaseDatos b = new BaseDatos();
      PrintWriter salida = response.getWriter();
      if (request.getParameter("Agregar") != null) {
        boolean inserto = b.inserta (
          request.getParameter("nombre"),
          request.getParameter("apellido_p"),
          request.getParameter("apellido_m"),
          request.getParameter("direccion"),
          request.getParameter("telefono"),
          request.getParameter("email")
        );
        if (inserto) {
          salida.println("<br>Usuario agregado");
        } else {
          salida.println("<br>No fue posible agregar el usuario");
        }
      } else {
        //Agrega la funcionalidad de consultar todos los usuarios
      }
    out.println("</body>");
  %>
</html>
```

This is the java file for this code, it's named on spanish, but I think nothing is too difficult:

```java
public class BaseDatos {
  Connection conexion = null;

  public BaseDatos() {
    conexion = null;
  }

  private boolean conecta() {
    try {
      String urlBD = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/practica2?user=root&password=";
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(urlBD);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public boolean inserta(
      String nom, String ap_p,
      String ap_m, String dir, String tel,
      String email) {
    try {
      if (conecta()) {
        String q = "insert into personas " +
            "(nombre,apellido_p,apellido_m,direccion,telefono,email) " +
            "values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement i = conexion.prepareStatement(q);
        i.setString(1, nom);
        i.setString(2, ap_p);
        i.setString(3, ap_m);
        i.setString(4, dir);
        i.setString(5, tel);
        i.setString(6, email);
        i.executeUpdate();
        i.close();
        conexion.close();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      return false;
    }
  }

  public String tablaUsuarios() {
    try {
      if (conecta()) {
        String q = "select * from personas";
        PreparedStatement p = conexion.prepareStatement(q);
        ResultSet r = p.executeQuery();
        String tabla = "<table border=\"3\" align=\"center\">";
        tabla += "<tr bgcolor=blue><th align=center>" +
            "<font color=white>Nombre</font></th>";
        tabla += "<th align=center><font color=white>Apellido</font></th></tr>";
        while (r.next()) {
          tabla += "<tr><td>" + r.getString("nombre") + 
              "</td><td>" + r.getString("apellido_p") + 
              "        </td></tr>";
        }
        r.close();
        p.close();
        conexion.close();
        return tabla;
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      return "";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is it inserting to database

Comment: you need to pass a parameter called "Agregar" to the page for it to do something.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole bunch of URL parameters that the JSP is expecting, the least is the parameter called "Agregar". You need to pass these parameters to the page for it to do further processing.

```
if (request.getParameter("Agregar")!= null){
            boolean inserto = b.inserta (
            request.getParameter("nombre"),
            request.getParameter("apellido_p"),
            request.getParameter("apellido_m"),
            request.getParameter("direccion"),
            request.getParameter("telefono"),
            request.getParameter("email")
            );
            if(inserto){
                salida.println("<br>Usuario agregado"); 
            }else{
                salida.println("<br>No fue posible agregar el usuario"); 
            }
            }else{
            //Agrega la funcionalidad de consultar todos los usuarios
            }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, parameter "Agregar" is needed to be put in the java, isn't? I'm very lost, just my second homework in jsp

Comment: pass it through URL something like this http://localhost:8080/test.jsp?Agregar=1234

Comment: sorry if too bothering, but, how do i pass it?

Comment: what is the URL you are using to see your page? in the same URL add it this "Agregar=1234" without quotes

Comment: I try it and it doesn't show the table yet, just display:


Usuario agregado Hola?

Comment: The code for showing the table is not there hence not showing up. All its doing is inserting row into the database.